# No output as stdout and stderr in the script

Tags: bash

I was developing and executing a Unix script where I need to check if a string exists in a file -

```
while read line
do
echo $line
grep -ir $line /c/*.json >> q1
done < a
```

But no output lines are getting logged in q1 file - in fact it is empty? Why - I do manually see a few string existing in target file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is the `/c/*` for 
But you can do grep on a file you don't need to read it first.

```
grep -i .json a >> q1
```

Comment: Thanks my issue was that the file from where I was reading string was of DOS format - I needed to run dos2unix on that file - after to which it started working fine